# Long unknown process when closing browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer, html5

Over a period of months, I've noticed heavy use of the hard drive when I shut down browsers. The worst of the worst is MSIE, which can take 10 minutes or so before it stops. Given the amount of time I've observed this, I'm sure it's not due to some other process running on my computer. It happens when I shut browsers down.

During this time, it can be more difficult to reopen the browser or open another browser. Firefox is the worst on this point; often refusing my requests to reopen until at least later in the process. Others can simply delay, but will eventually reopen.

It's become a greater irritation to me lately because I'm trying to do some multi-browser testing. When I successfully start another browser after shutting one down, I'm finding that the new browser session won't do some things properly (HTML5) until the other browser shut-down process has completed.

I hope someone recognizes or can identify the problem and tell me how to deal with it.

Comment: How much RAM do you have? Do you have a lot of tabs open when closing the browsers?

Comment: 4GB on 64-bit Vista. Very few (possible only one) tabs, but have SQL Server and Tomcat running (related to the testing), a command window, couple of explorers and a few test files open. But I've noticed long shut downs even when I'm not testing and don't have all this stuff going.

Comment: That definitely sounds unusual. I've posted a few tools that may be useful in finding out what's causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Own Answer: Windows Vista Search Indexing (confirmed ... problem fixed by disabling same) and SuperFetch (confirmed ... problem fixed by disabling same).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [DiskMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896646) to try to figure out what is generating all this disk activity, and perhaps [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) as well.